# How to clear the Firefox cache from Windows 7 command line

Tags: firefox, caching, command

I like to include my Firefox profile directory in my automated backups but I don't really want to back up cached pages/images. I've searched high and low but everything I've found is either outdated (delete the contents of the [ffprofile]\Cache folder) or the instructions delete the entire contents of the profile directory! There must be some way to do this with modern FF builds...

Comment: The link posted by jwir3 is an old one but one of the posts there helped: "And if you're not using Windows or the cache folder is somewhere else for a different reason, the location is listed in 'about:cache'." When I went to 'about:cache', there's an entry (under 'disk') called 'Storage disk location' - and that led me to the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a command line option to clear the file caches directly (patches accepted, though, I suppose. ;> ). As a workaround, though, you can clear the caches through this method via the command line:

```
# Create a test profile (Do this once)
PROFILENAME=testProfile
PROFILEDIR=/tmp/profileDir
$ firefox -no-remote -CreateProfile $PROFILENAME $PROFILEDIR

# Clear the cache of the profile (Do this every time you want to run the script)
# This uses the mac osx path for caches
# See http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=502357 for more information about where the caches are located on different operating systems
rm ~/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/*.${PROFILENAME}/entries/cache2/*
```

Note that I tested this on Mac OSX, and it works fine, although it's somewhat of a hack to get around the lack of a profile identifier.

Comment: Thanks for responding but I'm trying to do this in Windows. (I've edited the question to reflect that.) I checked the FF profile directory in Windows but there's no "entries" folder within the profile folder.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might struggle with this: just go to about:cache - the location of the cache files is listed in the 'disk' section under 'Storage disk location'. Once you have the location, append "\entries" and do a simple "del /f /q [location]"